# I can't put text like [static] on the right side of the page for a certain function in doxygen

Tags: doxygen, documentation-generation, code-documentation

What is the syntax to put a short test note or a tag on the right side of the page to indicate some kind of a property of a function like a nothrow or static.

see the image how Qt does it.
[image]

I could not find any information on the doxygen site.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?  A static function should automatically have the `[static]`. See also the doxygen commands `\static` and `\qualifier`

Comment: You can easily take a look at [how Qt does this](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/1fbcb411e12047961dac157f5fbcd327e0a47833/src/corelib/text/qstring.h#L686)